# Custom switching behavior of QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt

### Problem

I want to make a QTabWidget that, for some tabs, switches to the same page of the child QStackedWidget instead of an individual page per tab. This is because some list is needed on multiple tabs (but on others it is not, so I can't just put it above the tabs), but I only want to have one list object, so fill it only once, no synchronizing between tabs and so on.

Abstract Example:

- GUI imports some data
- User hat several workflows (tabs) to select from

  - plotting
  - frequency analysis
  - export
  - statistics

on all tabs the GUI needs a kind of channel selector, so a list of available channels in the data and a list of selected channels.
On the plotting tab, there needs to be a selection of the x-axis for the plot as well.

statistics is in my example the odd one, on this tab there is only information displayed, that is automatically calculated for all channels, only some checkboxes there for example.

### Idea

I don't use a QTabWidget, but a QTabBar and a QStackedWidget. Problem here is, that I'm unable to achieve the look of a QTabWidget, so with a frame of the selected tab around the content of the page of the QStackedWidget (for the moment I don't care about the formatting of the tabs themselves):

[image: QTabWidget vs QTabBar and QStackedWidget]

### Current Solution

Now, the way I made it work was to use a QTabWidget, disconnect the currentChanged() signal of the containing QTabBar from the containing QStackedWidget and implemented my own slot to switch between pages in the QStackedWidget (see code example).

The way I did this seems a bit complicated and not really beautiful, since I can't get the pointer of the QStackedWidget inside the QTabWidget directly.

### Example

Here's my example code for both variations in the picture:

main.cpp (equal for both examples):

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "mainwindow.h"    

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{        
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mw;
    mw.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTabBar>
#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QStackedWidget>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    // constructor
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    void switchTab1(int index);
    void switchTab2(int index);
    QTabWidget *tabwidget1_;
    QTabBar *tabwidget2_;
    QStackedWidget *stack1_;
    QStackedWidget *stack2_;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLayout>

#include "mainwindow.h"

// constructor
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{    
    //LEFT
    QWidget *listTab1 = new QWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *listTab1Layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    listTab1Layout->addWidget(new QListWidget);
    listTab1Layout->addWidget(new QListWidget);
    listTab1->setLayout(listTab1Layout);

    QWidget *buttonTab1 = new QWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *buttonTab1Layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    buttonTab1Layout->addWidget(new QPushButton);
    buttonTab1Layout->addWidget(new QPushButton);
    buttonTab1Layout->addStretch();
    buttonTab1->setLayout(buttonTab1Layout);

    tabwidget1_ = new QTabWidget;
    tabwidget1_->addTab(listTab1,"tab1");
    tabwidget1_->addTab(new QWidget,"tab2");
    tabwidget1_->addTab(new QWidget,"tab3");
    tabwidget1_->addTab(buttonTab1,"tab4");

    // extracts the stacked widget, parentWidget() returns QObject,
    // so it needs to be casted to QStackedWidget
    stack1_ = qobject_cast<QStackedWidget*>(tabwidget1_->widget(0)->parentWidget());
    // extract the tabbar
    QTabBar *tabbar = tabwidget1_->tabBar();
    // disconnects the switching of tabs, so I can implement my own function
    disconnect(tabbar,&QTabBar::currentChanged,0,0);
    // reconnect to manipulate the switching
    connect(tabbar,&QTabBar::currentChanged,this,&MainWindow::switchTab1);

    // RIGHT
    QWidget *listTab2 = new QWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *listTab2Layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    listTab2Layout->addWidget(new QListWidget);
    listTab2Layout->addWidget(new QListWidget);
    listTab2->setLayout(listTab2Layout);

    QWidget *buttonTab2 = new QWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *buttonTab2Layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    buttonTab2Layout->addWidget(new QPushButton);
    buttonTab2Layout->addWidget(new QPushButton);
    buttonTab2Layout->addStretch();
    buttonTab2->setLayout(buttonTab2Layout);

    tabwidget2_ = new QTabBar;
    tabwidget2_->addTab("tab1");
    tabwidget2_->addTab("tab2");
    tabwidget2_->addTab("tab3");
    tabwidget2_->addTab("tab4");

    stack2_ = new QStackedWidget;

    stack2_->addWidget(listTab2);
    stack2_->addWidget(buttonTab2);
    connect(tabwidget2_,&QTabBar::currentChanged,this,&MainWindow::switchTab2);

    QVBoxLayout *rightLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    rightLayout->addWidget(tabwidget2_);
    rightLayout->addWidget(stack2_);

    // ADD TO MAIN
    QWidget *mainWidget = new QWidget;
    QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(tabwidget1_);
    mainLayout->addLayout(rightLayout);
    mainWidget->setLayout(mainLayout);
    setCentralWidget(mainWidget);
}

void MainWindow::switchTab1(int index)
{
    //    stack_->setCurrentIndex(index);
    //    return;
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
        stack1_->setCurrentIndex(0);
        break;
    case 3:
        stack1_->setCurrentIndex(3);
        break;
    }
    emit tabwidget1_->currentChanged(index);
}

void MainWindow::switchTab2(int index)
{
    //    stack_->setCurrentIndex(index);
    //    return;
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
        stack2_->setCurrentIndex(0);
        break;
    case 3:
        stack2_->setCurrentIndex(1);
        break;
    }
}
```

### Question

**Do you know a better way to achieve the desired behavior?**
Or would you recommend a different way altogether to create very similar tabs?

Edit 1: better title

Comment: The task that they implement seems redundant since I see that instead of adding 2 tabs with 2 separate widgets you are using a QStackedWidget, that is, visually it is the same. Maybe this is wrong, could you please explain to me what is the difference if instead of adding the widget that has 2 QListWidget and and 2 QPushButtona a QStackedWidget you add it directly to QTabWidget each one.

Comment: You should use `QListView` instead of `QListWidget`, so that several views can share the same model. Then you only need to update one model. If necessary, you can also use proxy models to get different sorting and filtering behaviour for each view.

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm not sure I understand your question. The example just hold my initial idea of using a QTabBar and a QStackedWidget instead of a QTabWidget to have foll control over the switching behavior. If you compile and run the example, you'll see that both the left and the right implementation switch to the QListWidgets if you click on tab 1-3 and to the QPushButtons on Tab 4.
Both sides implement the same, but:

- left side rather complicated connect / disconnect, empty widgets
- right side ugly

Comment: @ekhumoro that is a good suggestion and I will look into that! This would make my complicated attempt obsolete, I would just add the necessary view on each tab and do the work in the model.